# How to catch email deletion on the main inbox explorer?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I'm having problems catching the deletion event for emails that are deleted on the inbox explorer. None of the events I've tried catch this. `MailItem.BeforeDelete` only triggers if the email is deleted using the inspectors delete button, which is fine but it only catches a portion of deletions. `Explorer.BeforeItemCut` only triggers when the user uses Ctrl+X. `Explorer.BeforeMove` doesn't trigger either, I thought that may "deletion" was really just moving the email to the *Deleted Items* folder.

I thought of maybe catching when an email arrives in the *Deleted Items* folder, but `MAPIFolder` items don't seem to have events. So, I'm not sure where else to look.

Just to make sure, by deleting an email I mean when the user hits the red X below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Deleted Items folder's Items collection.

It will not of course fire in case of Shift+Delete.